# Auto create thing on aws iot core dashboard uses esp8266 ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, esp8266, aws-iot, arduino-esp8266, mongoose-os

I'm using AWS-IOT core to handle problem about MQTT for Esp8266 . I'm creating things on AWS-IOT core dashboard and setup that things for my Esp8266, but When I setup for 10000 devices , I cannot create each device one by one. So Does anyone have an solution?. Sorry My English is not good

Comment: I also needed to get MQTT going on ESP8266 with AWS IoT a few months back.  I just followed this tutorial from AWS and I was able to get everything working.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/aws-iot-on-mongoose-os-part-1/

Comment: Try maybe to create a shell/bash script based around the aws-iot-setup command in step 6 for your 1000 devices?